# iPhone - debugging "pointer being freed was not allocated" errors

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, malloc-history

When over freeing a pointer you may see an error such as

"pointer being freed was not allocated"

When debugging with the simulator, I add a build argument MallocStackLogging = YES - this allows me to use malloc_history in the terminal to track down where I have over freed a pointer.

If I debug on the device with this build argument I get all sorts of console errors "cannot create stack log files" etc.

Oddly, I get some over freed pointer errors appearing on the device, but not on the simulator.

Has anyone had any experience tracking these down using the device itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Another way to do this. Make sure to turn NSZombie on so it reports the memory address of the object that is getting the extra release. Then Run with Performance Tool->Object Allocations. This will bring up instruments. Look at the Console log as provided by Xcode organizer. Once you get the crash lookup the memory address in instruments. You will see the entire history of mallocs/frees on that object, as well as links straight into your code.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it with these exact directions (in Xcode 4.2.1) - I had to run through Xcode, then attach Instruments while it was running. I had "Enable Zombie Objects" turned on for my current Scheme, and once I triggered the exception, Instruments latched on like a champ and took me to the history for the zombie's address. I looked at the stack trace for the initial allocation, and saw an unnecessary `[autorelease]` that was causing the exception. Awesome tool!

Comment: The complete "how to" is shown on the WWDC video from 2010 called "Session 311 - Advanced Memory Analysis With Instruments" at 31:50.

Answer (score 1):

I generally use NSZombie for such things, check [this](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DebuggingAutorelease) out

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the MallocStackLogging env variables on the target executable...

To access these settings, select your executable from the Groups & Files pane in XCode, then Get Info.

Go to the Arguments tab and add the following entries into the “Variables to be set in the environment” box:

Answer (score 0):

Please test the program for memory leaks,Also check autoreleases and whether you are releasing objects properly or not.Also we need to check whether a released object has a memory allocated or not.You also need to be careful regarding autorelease,because accidentally we might release an array or a string or any object that is already autoreleased...hope it helps and works!

**Tip: You can test for leaks by analyzing your project(click shift+command+k)**