# What does this error mean? malloc: *** error for object 0x103f000: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, memory-management

What does that mean? Getting this in the console during usage of my app in debug mode:

> malloc: *** error for object
>   0x103f000: pointer being freed was not
>   allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Does that mean I'm over-releasing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295778/iphone-debugging-pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated-errors) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424210/iphone-development-pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated).

Looks like you may be dereferencing something that's null, or something similar. I suggest that you post your code here to get some more helpful responses. I'm not too familiar with the iPhone API, so this may not be much help...