# Boost directory_iterator causes crash

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I've been trying to iterate through a directory using this sample which I found with a quick google search:

```
namespace bf = boost::filesystem;
bf::path p("somedir");
bf::directory_iterator end_iter;
for (bf::directory_iterator iter(p); iter != end_iter; ++iter) {

}
```

However, when running this through Terminal, the default constructor causes this:
`testapp(6538) malloc: *** error for object 0x10fee9820: pointer being freed was not allocated`. Further debugging showed that this occurs in the constructor of the directory_iterator. Has this happened to anyone else?
If I run this through NetBeans everything runs fine.

I use OSX 10.8.3 and GCC 4.8

Comment: can you share somedir ?? I think it should be something like  boost::filesystem::path p("c:\\dir");

Comment: @MAG I use OSX, so no C:\\. The path is also relative to the working directory and I've included a check to see if the directory exists. The directory is just a normal directory containing a bunch of .txt files.

Comment: sry i missed that .. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/example/tut3.cpp might be helpful but its strange you have different behaviour with netbeans which might  happen if you are having different versions of boost on your system ...

Comment: I tried the example and I get the same problem. Thanks for trying to help though. I'm sure I've only got one version installed, I installed it through MacPorts :|

Comment: check this out ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420990/what-does-this-error-mean-malloc-error-for-object-0x103f000-pointer-being

Comment: @MAG Does that explain why it's working in NetBeans but not without NetBeans? The constructor of directory_iterator is causing the problem as far as I know

Comment: I got it working with Unix readdir, but that's not really ideal. Any other aspect of boost::filesystem works perfectly apart from directory iteration...

Comment: I get similar problems if "somedir" is not a directory or doesn't exist. The sample code from 'tut3' checks this first.

Comment: @doctorlove the directory exists.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact issue.  For me, the problem ended up being that the Boost libraries were compiled with a different C++ compiler than I was using on my project (clang for Boost and gcc for my stuff).  I recompiled Boost with GCC and success.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I compiled everything with the same compiler. I compiled boost using MacPorts (which uses GCC as far as I know) and GCC for my project.

Comment: MacPorts will use the system default compiler (which is probably clang).  MacPorts specifically will **not** use gcc by default, cf. [https://trac.macports.org/wiki/UsingTheRightCompiler].  So unless you've taken steps to make gcc the default, MacPorts is not using gcc to build boost.

From that link, you can instruct MacPorts to build a package with gcc like so:
port install boost configure.compiler=macports-gcc-4.8

Comment: I set my default MacPorts compiler to gcc48